# Dialog box positioning

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

I need to show the dialog where i clicked. If i click below link the dialog box must show below where i click the link the dialog box must appear in same position but in my code dialog box is showing at the top center of the page even ever we click the link.

jquery

```
$(".showTemplateDialog").dialog('option', 'position', ['center',e.pageY]);
```

Please help me for the get the dialog box at the mouse position .

I tried the with the top and left position also . but i didn't get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

`$(".showTemplateDialog").dialog('option', 'position', [$(this).offset.left,$(this).offset.top]);`

have a look at dialog box positioning api for more info here: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

**UPDATE**: Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7b2RF/

Comment: I use this code  but dialog box is showing at the top only. i checked with alert box before the success function the alert box used  is showing where i clicked but in the success function the alert box used is showing at the top

Comment: Check out the live demo in update above, here i have cleaned up the same code a little bit in fiddle and uses class instead ID so you can use it for infinite number of elements of same class, in this case i've used "divs" class. 
hope this helps.

Comment: In ajax i use                                   success:function(objRequest)
            {
             
              alert(left);          
             $('.showTemplateDialog').html($.trim(objRequest));
               $('.showTemplateDialog').dialog("open");
              $(".showTemplateDialog").dialog({
                            position: [left + 15, top + 20]
                         });
              
   
            },                                                                     inside the success the alert also showing at the top

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might get you the idea how to do it:

HTML:

```
<div id="one" class="divs"></div>
<div id="two" class="divs"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.divs {
    float: left;
    height: 48px;
    width: 80px;
    border: 1px solid #55f;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $div = $('#two');
    var left = $div.offset().left;
    var top= $div.offset().top;
    $('<p>Some dialog</p>').dialog({position: [left + 20, top + 20]});
});
```

Here is the link to [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yuKhL/1/).

jQuery [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) returns element postion relative to document, while [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) returns relative to offset parent.